# Video player controls not showing in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, video-player

I am using Mediaplayer.js file for creating media player in sharepoint 2013 , everything works fine but controls(Play , Pause , Volume, Full Screen) not showing  ..

Here is my code that i am using for creating video player in sharepoint 2013

```
 mediaPlayer.createMediaPlayer(
                videoHolder,   videoHolder.id,  '400px',   '266px',
                 {
                     displayMode: 'Inline',
                     mediaTitle: 'Video Entry',
                     mediaSource: videoURL,
                     previewImageSource:'',
                     autoPlay: true,
                     loop: false,
                     mediaFileExtensions:'wmv;wma;avi;mpg;mp3;mp4',
                     silverlightMediaExtensions:'wmv;wma;mp3;mp4'
                 }
            );
```

any property for show controls in this function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is HTML5 - in the video tag just add controls attribute

eg

```
<video controls>
<source>
</video>
```

Comment: Is it an HTML5 site?

Based on your code it looks like you got it from here: http://psnagarkar.blogspot.ca/2013/06/javascript-to-create-media-player-in.html

Comment: Not flavour of SharePoint but the doctype of the page being rendered. XHTML or HTML5?

When the player is rendered in the browser what does the source look like?

Comment: yes..you are right..when page is render , after that i will edit controls attribute through developer tools or firebug in my rendered html  , controls will show ...otherwise not ...